# C# Adding Colors to Custom Expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors, expression

Is there any way in MSVS2010 to give an expression (for example, the '=>' expression) a custom color when written, similar to how other keywords are indicated with special colors?

Comment: You might need to create a code editor VS extension for this.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expression are syntax highlighted as of time they where created. For example check out **ScottGu** blog http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-orcas-language-feature-lambda-expressions

If you want custom color formatting in c# then check out

**https://studiostyl.es/**